# How to change account and basket icons in RWD theme?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I would like to change these icons to my own custom ones:

[image]

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is using image sprite. 
You can find the image on rwd skin folder > images > icon_sprite.png.

So you need to edit the image on photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the PSD file that was used to create the sprites in the RWD theme by looking for the `Working With Sprites` heading on this page: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide#customize-theme-images